# Flutter print only one value from response

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My response return:

`print(response.body);`

I/flutter (31140): `{"code":99,"email":"mail@mail.com"}`

How print only `code` or `email`

I/flutter (31140): `{"code":99}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use jsonDecode function from dart:convert library

```
import 'dart:convert';
Map<String, dynamic> myResponse= jsonDecode(response.body);
print('Code: ${myResponse['code']}  Email: ${myResponse['email']} ');
```